# Confidence Interval Calculation for a small decimal numbers

Tags: r, confidence-interval

By Using this Dummy datasets: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M6FM6okShiEciRW3UsLC8Gb4KRyjKrrs/view?usp=sharing

I defined Custom Function to calculate preferred  Confidence Interval and then calculate number of value that match in the lower - upper bound of Confidence Interval

```
count_by_confidence_interval <- function(vector, interval_vec=c()){
  confidence_interval <- function(vector, interval=0.95) {
    vec_sd <- sd(vector)
    n <- length(vector)
    vec_mean <- mean(vector)
    error <- qt((interval + 1)/2, df = n - 1) * vec_sd / sqrt(n)
    writeLines(paste0("Confidence Interval of ",interval*100, " %"))
    result <- c("lower" = vec_mean - error, "upper" = vec_mean + error)
    return(result)
  }
  for(b in 1:length(interval_vec)){
    confint_result <- confidence_interval(vector, interval_vec[b])
    all_length <- length(vector)
    length_by_confint <- length(vector[vector >= confint_result[1] & vector <= confint_result[2]])
    writeLines("=========================================================================================")
    writeLines(paste0("By Confidence Interval of ",interval_vec[b]))
    writeLines(paste0("With Lower Bound = ",round(confint_result[1],5), " and Upper Bound = ",round(confint_result[2],5)))
    writeLines(paste0("Count Data in between of Confidence Interval: ", length_by_confint))
    writeLines(paste0("Count All Data: ", all_length))
    writeLines(paste0("This Represents of: ", round(length_by_confint/all_length,5),"% Data of All Data"))
    writeLines("=========================================================================================")
  }
}

dataset <- read.csv("dummy_data.csv")
count_by_confidence_interval(dataset$Value, c(0.95, 0.975))
```

Since the value of dummy datasests range variantly from -0.5 to 0.5 and then somehow 95% Confidence Interval of value column resulting Lower Bounds of 0.03517 and Upper Bounds of 0.03543 (which ranges very near), this causing only a small proportion of dataset that valid in that confidence interval (<1%), So I wonder if the Confidence Interval calculation on this case is correctly defined? Since the standard deviation value is too small to make an interval bounds

Comment: A confidence interval is about a parameter (in your case the population mean), not about a sample. So it makes no sense to ask "how many % of the sample is within a CI".

Comment: @Michael M So the Confidence Interval is about calculating "Varying" Population Mean within an interval? its not about estimating mostly population distribution?

Comment: Almost., yes. It tells something about in what range the population mean might fall with high certainty. Where e.g. 95% certainty means: if you would repeat the same experiment over and over again, about 95% of the confidence intervals would cover the population mean (the population mean would be the same, but the intervals would depend on the sample).

Comment: Noted, thanks for your explanation @Michael M I was mixing the concept of confidence Interval.. Thats make more sense from your explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two comments from above:

A confidence interval (CI) is about a parameter (in your case the population mean), not about a sample. So it makes no sense to ask "how many % of the sample is within a CI".

The CI tells in what range the population mean might fall with high certainty. Where e.g. 95% certainty means: if you would repeat the same experiment over and over again, about 95% of the confidence intervals would cover the population mean (the population mean would be the same, but the intervals would depend on the sample)